# SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery fires callback before actual command ending

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, callback, ado.net

I have a long running stored procedure which performs heavy calculations and updates some thousands records, handling transactions internally to keep each record consistent while minimizing blocking and allowing to query for the process progress.

I'm working on SQL Server 2008, .Net Framework 4 and VB 2010

I attempt to call this SP asynchronously from my logic tier by means of SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery, passing this method a callback to perform some cleanup and logging in both cases the command completes successfully or fails. Nevertheless the callback function is called before the SP really ends, with AsyncResult.IsCompleted=true and so, when this callback performs SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery it hangs waiting for the command to complete or timeout expires.

I read many articles but so far the pattern seems quite straightforward and everywhere it's stated that the callback will be fired only upon command completion.

Briefly, my code is essentially like this:

```
Public Shared Sub ExecAsync(sp_call As String, async_connection As String)
  '...
  Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sp_call, New SqlClient.SqlConnection(async_connection))
  Dim callback As New AsyncCallback(AddressOf CallbackAsync)
  cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, cmd)
  '...
  'try catch ommited
End Sub

Public Shared Sub CallbackAsync(ByVal result As IAsyncResult)
  Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = TryCast(result.AsyncState, SqlClient.SqlCommand)
  cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(result)
  If cmd.Connection IsNotNothing Then
     cmd.Connection.Close()
  End If
  '...
  'try catch and logging ommited
End Sub
```

And I can simulate the behavior of the real SP with this simple script:

```
declare @i int
declare @iId int
select @iId = 1 

select @i = 0
delete xxx_xxx --trivial test table
where id = @iId 

while @i < 100
  begin
   begin transaction
   insert into xxx_xxx (id, hora, iNum) values (@iId, getdate(), @i)
   commit transaction
   select @i += 1

   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
  end
```

In the many attemps I made, I found that if I remove the transactions in the SQL script the behavior is what is expected and the callback fires at the very end of the execution.
Performing the transactions the callback fires before the end of the execution, commenting them out, it fires at the end.

Unfortunately, to avoid the transactions is not an option in the real scenario.

Is there any reason for this, or more precisely, some way to avoid it and have the callback function to be actually called after the SP ends?

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Gustavo Sosa

Comment: Can you the post your code that runs after this line: `cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, cmd)`

Comment: Have you tried using `ExecuteReader` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`, just to see the behavior?

Comment: @BateTech, after cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery I just catch any exception and the sub ends.

Comment: @Josh Part, yes I tried BeginExecuteReader as well, and the behavior is the same.

Comment: I see you mention "transactions" in your question. How many does the script have? Have you identified if the callback is being fired after the end of the first transaction? What if you have only one?